How can I run these 2 calls to sum values as one call in EF Core?
Is there a way to make these 2 calls 1? Both are from the same table, just different values.
var grossAmount = await _dbContext.StripeTransfers
  .Where(p => p.StripePayoutId == payout.StripePayoutId)
  .Select(p => p.GrossAmount)
.SumAsync();

var totalTokens = await _dbContext.StripeTransfers
  .Where(p => p.StripePayoutId == payout.StripePayoutId)
  .Select(p => p.Tokens)
.SumAsync();


It may be helpful to tackle the problem from the other direction: Try to make an SQL statement that gives you want you want, then try to translate it into EF-LINQ.

What is the database you are using?

The only real difference (other than object names) from the answers in the above-linked question, is that you would likely want to end your query with .FirstOrDefaultAsync() instead of .FirstOrDefault().

As recommended in a comment making a SQL statement might be more efficient here, but if you are wanting to stay in realm of EF and LINQ you can do something like this:
var result = await _dbContext.StripeTransfers
    .Where(p => p.StripePayoutId == payout.StripePayoutId)
    .GroupBy(p => p.StripePayoutId)
    .Select(g => new
    {
        GrossAmountSum = g.Sum(p => p.GrossAmount),
        TokensSum = g.Sum(p => p.Tokens)
    })
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

// Here you can do whatever you want with variables.
var grossAmount = result?.GrossAmountSum ?? 0;
var totalTokens = result?.TokensSum ?? 0;


What is the purpose of the groupby out of curiosity ?

@TravTanker - It isn't strictly necessary since the filter already limits it to a single payout, it's useful to illustrate the concept.
